# Implement Window Drag and Drop WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, window

I had to create a new Window from scratch using MahApps.Metro like [this](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#roll_your_own_window). This creates for you a borderlesss Window without the standard Window buttons (Close, Restore or Minimze).

I implemented these buttons and it works pretty well. The thing that I see that is not like all anothers windows is the behavior that allows the user to change the position of the window, using drag and drop.

I was looking for but I couldn't figure how to do it.

How should I implement the behavior of drag and drop in a non-standard window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your window handles the event **MouseLeftButtonDown**:

```
    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

This works on standard WPF applications, not sure if Metro apps can use this.

If you prefer, you can handle this event using another control. For instance, you can handle it with an image control that simulates a title bar.